# cron error Fatal error: Call to undefined function filter_xss()

Tags: 6, cron

I am running a remote command on my server to execute cron.php and I get this error : Fatal error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function filter_xss() in /home/k1004/html/www_dem
o/oan/srcs/includes/common.inc on line 655
Does anyone have an idea about where it comes from??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a [patch](http://drupal.org/node/1174496) that solved the problem. It seems that it was a problem in the core update I have made.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure the filter module is enable.

I think this problem is because you have a function call to [filter_xss()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--filter--filter.module/function/filter_xss/5) before the filter module load.

Is your Drupal is stand install or this problem exist after install other module?

Comment: Yes I think normally the filter module is enable since I can't see a way to enable/disable it. I guess it may be one of the modules I have installed but I can't figure out which one.